# Prepend em um EditText usando TextWatcher

Tags: android, edittext

Como fazer um *prepend* no Android?

Atualmente faço alguns *append*, mas não vi como fazer um *prepend* no evento `onTextChanged`.

A razão é pra colocar um `(` antes dos 2 primeiros dígitos de um telefone, pra ficar a máscara `(xx) x xxxx - xxxx`.

Ou seja, esse `(` seria inserido depois que o usuário colocasse o primeiro dígito mas antes do mesmo.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use o método `afterTextChanged()` do TextWatcher:

```
@Override
public void afterTextChanged(Editable editable) {
    if(editable.length() == 1 && !editable.toString().equals("(")){
        editable.insert(0, "(");
    }
}
```

Caso queira que o `(` seja eliminado quando for eliminado o primeiro número, use:

```
@Override
public void afterTextChanged(Editable editable) {
    if(editable.toString().equals("(")){
        editable.clear();
        return;
    }
    if(editable.length() == 1) {
        editable.insert(0, "(");
    }
}
```